# looping over multiple excel sheets to create concat dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet that has multiple sheets each corresponding to 1 year of monthly data from Jan-Dec for a specific index (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)

For example:

```
Sheet_2022
    Jan-2022 Feb-2022 Mar-2022 Apr-2022 May-2022 Jun-2022 Jul-2022 Aug-2022 Sep-2022 Oct-2022 Nov-2022 Dec-2022
A       1       6       9           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
B       6       5       9           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
C       32      6       9           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
D       1       7       9           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
E       4       8       9           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
F       8       9       9           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
```

```
Sheet_2023
    Jan-2023 Feb-2023 Mar-2023 Apr-2023 May-2023 Jun-2023 Jul-2023 Aug-2023 Sep-2023 Oct-2023 Nov-2023 Dec-2023
A       2       6       5           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
B       5       5       34          5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
C       32      6       3           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
D       8       7       2           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
E       9       8       5           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
F       0       9       8           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
```

```
Sheet_2024
    Jan-2024 Feb-2024 Mar-2024 Apr-2024 May-2024 Jun-2024 Jul-2024 Aug-2024 Sep-2024 Oct-2024 Nov-2024 Dec-2024
A       1       6       2           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
B       6       5       3           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
C       32      6       4           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
D       1       7       5           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
E       4       8       6           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
G       8       9       7           5       8       5       8       4           9       4       0       3
```

I am using the below code to read all sheets and save it in same dataframe:

```
for i in result:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename_Value, sheet_name = i)
    df_Value.append(df)
df_Value = pd.concat(df_Value)
```

But this is giving data is somewhat different format:

```
df_Value
    Jan-2022 Feb-2022 Mar-2022  Jan-2023 Feb-2023 Mar-2023  Jan-2024 Feb-2024 Mar-2024
A     1         6       9                       
B     6         5       9                       
C     32        6       9                       
D     1         7       9                       
E     4         8       9                       
F     8         9       9                       
A                                   2       6       5                           
B                                   5       5       34                          
C                                   32      6       3                           
D                                   8       7       2                           
E                                   9       8       5                           
F                                   0       9       8                           
A                                                               1       6       2           
B                                                               6       5       3           
C                                                               32      6       4           
D                                                               1       7       5           
E                                                               4       8       6           
G                                                               8       9       7
```

I am looking to create a single dataframe where the values will be like:

```
df_Value
    Jan-2022 Feb-2022 Mar-2022  Jan-2023 Feb-2023 Mar-2023  Jan-2024 Feb-2024 Mar-2024
A     1         6       9           2       6       5           1       6       2                       
B     6         5       9           5       5       34          6       5       3                       
C     32        6       9           32      6       3           32      6       4                       
D     1         7       9           8       7       2           1       7       5                       
E     4         8       9           9       8       5           4       8       6                       
F     8         9       9           0       9       8                                   
G                                                               8       9       7
```

Is there a easier way to do this?

Comment: You want `pd.concat(df_Value, axis=1)`?

Comment: i tried this, ut in this case the column headers are taken from the first sheet itself. Other headers are getting ignored and its appending the data from other sheets below the previous columns itself

Comment: Try `pd.join()`

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar There is no such function in pandas

Comment: Also, the row mismatch (Check row G in Sheet 3) will be an issue here if I use pd.concat

Comment: @RSM No it'll be fine. I tried `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)` and it works.

Comment: @Zero how do i get ```df1, df2, df3```. While using for loop we will just get one df, right?

Comment: You are storing all dataframes in a list by appending them after each iteration. It's the same as me writing `[df1, df2, df3]` so there shouldn't be any differences. All that matters is how your files are being read. Can you print the dataframes after reading them in the `for` loop?

Comment: @Zero sorry, `df.join()` should work: [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar Yeah `df.join()` exists. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas-merge) will do exactly what you want.

`concat` will be more in line with what you are asking since merge only works with two dataframes at a time.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

t22_1 = StringIO("""\
i,Jan22,Feb22,Mar22
A,1,4,2
B,6,2,3
C,7,3,0
""")

t22_2 = StringIO("""\
i,Apr22,May22,Jun22
A,0,5,7
B,6,3,8
D,1,7,9
""")

df22_1 = pd.read_csv(t22_1, index_col="i")

df22_2 = pd.read_csv(t22_2, index_col="i")

pd.concat([df22_1, df22_2], axis=1)
# or
pd.merge(df22_1, df22_2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")

--
   Jan22  Feb22  Mar22  Apr22  May22  Jun22
i                                          
A    1.0    4.0    2.0    0.0    5.0    7.0
B    6.0    2.0    3.0    6.0    3.0    8.0
C    7.0    3.0    0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
D    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    7.0    9.0
```

NB. I use StringIO to avoid writing file, keep on loading data as you do now.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way you can try, but I can't guarantee it is a better solution.

```
data = {'jan21':[1,2,3,4],'feb21':[2,3,4,5]}
data1 = {'jan22':[1,2,3,4],'feb22':[2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df[list(df1.columns)]=df1
print(df)

   jan21  feb21  jan22  feb22
0      1      2      1      2
1      2      3      2      3
2      3      4      3      4
3      4      5      4      5
```

Since you have created all yours dataframes from the same sheet, I can think of using `list(df.columns)` to merge your dataframes together.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for i in result:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename_Value, sheet_name = i)
    dataframe[list(df.columns)] = df
```

Comment: Please let me know if this works in your case, thank you